# woman due to be put to death

Tags: grammar

*An Iranian woman due to be put to death for killing a man she said was trying to sexually abuse her is reported to have had her execution postponed.*

I would like to ask about the word *due* in the sentence above. Does it function as the adjective or preposition there? Can I rewrite the sentence without the change of the meaning in this way: *An Iranian woman who is facing the death penalty for killing a man she said was trying to sexually abuse her is reported to have had her execution postponed.*

Answer (score 1):

It's an adjective as in *The payment is due.*

The sentence says that the punishment of death is pending for the woman. By the way I found that sentence a bit complex! :)